# Get number from HTML id using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Alright, so I have an HTML element as `<div id="slide_item_#">` where `#` is a number. What I would like to do, using Javascript, is get the number from the id. So I would assume a regular expression, I just don't know how to use them in Javascript.

```
var html_id = "slide_item_3";
var id_number = /* code here so that id_number == 3 */ ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just parse the string without the prefix using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), like this:

```
var id_number = parseInt(html_id.replace('slide_item_',''), 10);
```

An improvement, if you have the option, would involve naming your classes for your element the same as your id (i.e., "slide_item"), except that your id would have the correct number appended to the end (i.e., "slide_item2"). Then, in your code, you would simply use `this.className` instead of explicitly using 'slide_item_', and the rest of this code would be more dynamic

Answer (score 2):

```
var id_number = parseInt(html_id.substr(11));
```

Comment: No code example that includes `parseInt` can be complete without the advice to always use `parseInt(string, 10)` (*i.e.* specify the radix 10) because otherwise, a leading zero (as in "010") will cause the number to be interpreted as *octal*.

Comment: +1 though because your code performs the best of the three answers in so far. http://jsperf.com/get-number-from-id

Answer (score 2):

```
var html_id = "slide_item_3";
var id_number = +html_id.split('_').pop();
```

Comment: To clarify how this works, `.split('_')` turns the string into an array, `.pop()` removes and returns the last element of that array, and `+` at the beginning casts the result to a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the prefix or suffix... you only want the ID number:

```
var id_number = html_id.replace(/\D+/,""); // Remove all non-digit characters
```

will result in:

```
var html_id = "slide_item_3"  // 3  
var html_id = "foo45bar"      // 45
var html_id = "1-item-X"      // 1
var html_id = "1-item-2"      // 12 (take care of such cases!)
```